# Ruby: rm cannot remove file permissions denied

Tags: ruby, file, delete-file

I am trying to delete a file I created in a ruby script I am using the following to try and delete it;

```
x = `cmd /c rm c:\\temp\\secret.txt`

File.delete("c:\\temp\\secret.txt")
```

When I try to delete it I am getting a error for permissions denied. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: When you created the file in the script, did you close it properly? Is there a chance that your script has the file locked?

Comment: This is my problem: secret = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("c://temp//secret.txt"). Due to it using the file it wont let me delete it after.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
require 'fileutils' 
FileUtils::chmod(0644, "c://temp//secret.txt")
FileUtils.rm '"c://temp//secret.txt", :force => true
```

My guess is that Chef is changing the mode to make it hard to read. You can verify this by running `ls -l` from cygwin or running a stat from inside Ruby